# Foreman: Use different Procfile in development and production

Tags: heroku, sinatra, rack, foreman, shotgun

I have a homemade Sinatra application for which I intend to use Heroku to host it.

I use foreman and shotgun in development, with the following Procfile:

```
web: shotgun config.ru -s thin -o 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV
```

It works great with both development and production. But the thing is, **I don't want to use shotgun in production** since it's too slow.

#### Can we use separate Procfile configurations for both dev and prod?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You could use two `Procfiles` (e.g. `Procfile` and `Procfile.dev`) and use [`foreman`s `-f` option](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/#EXAMPLES) to select a different one to use in dev:

In dev (`Procfile.dev` contains your `shotgun` web process):

```
foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

In production, `foreman start` will pick up the normal `Procfile`.

Alternatively you could create a `bin` directory in your app with a script to start the appropriate web server depending on `$RACK_ENV` (an idea I found in a [comment made by the creator of Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/12#issuecomment-2656011), so worth considering).

Comment: Would you by chance know if there is a way to tell Heroku to run a different Procfile?

Comment: @darko no, there is no way to specify a custom Procfile for Heroku to run with. It will always use the one named `Procfile`.

Comment: To avoid the `-f Procfile.dev` parameter you can create a `.foreman` file with `procfile: Procfile.dev`in it

Comment: @bgentry that's terrifying, is that intentional?

Comment: For anyone happening to use node-foreman, the flag is -j instead of -f for some odd reason.

Answer (score 25):

@sharagoz 's comment on the selected answer, in my opinion, is the best option to allow you to still use `foreman start` without adding additional arguments AND keep your Procfile separate for Heroku.

> To avoid the -f Procfile.dev parameter you can create a .foreman file with `procfile: Procfile.dev` in it – Sharagoz

In my applications root directory I created a `.foreman` file and as the comment states

**.foreman**

```
procfile: Procfile.dev
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

**Procfile.dev**

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to handle it with one Procfile and environment variables.  I am using this on Heroku.

Set your environment:

```
export WEB_START_COMMAND='node index.js'
export WORKER_START_COMMAND='node worker.js'
```

The Procfile:

```
web: eval '$WEB_START_COMMAND'
worker: eval '$WORKER_START_COMMAND'
```

Export different start command in your server and dev environments.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when there's a `$PORT` on the command

Comment: This is somewhat limited if you want to have a different set of processes per environment. @sharagoz solution is more flexible.

Comment: In my case it turned out to be a pretty good solution, simple and working.

Answer (score 2):

For those still looking for this, according to the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) `foreman` is not needed anymore. You can simply use:

`heroku local -f Procfile.dev`