# How can I have a distinct Procfile for local development vs Heroku deployment?

Tags: heroku, foreman

In my local environment, I want to start MongoDB, for instance, but on Heroku, it is not needed.

How can I have a different set of processes on my local environment vs Heroku?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use different Procfile in development and production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592798/use-different-procfile-in-development-and-production)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create two Procfile with distinct extensions.

So you'll have

./Procfile with the processes as you intend them for Heroku
./Procfile.local with the processes as you need them locally

when starting foreman locally you'll need to type:
foreman start -f Procfile.local