# Conditional server start on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sh

To avoid issues in development with Foreman I need to I need to wrap the Puma server in a Socks proxy for Quotaguard to get a static IP in production and production only.

Using a link to this [article](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/12#issuecomment-2656011) that I found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592798/use-different-procfile-in-development-and-production) I implemented the following code in bin/web call from Procfile.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$RACK_ENV" == "production" ]; then
  echo Using qgsocksify to wrap Puma
  bin/qgsocksify bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
else
  echo Using straight Puma
  bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
fi
```

Although the environment is production set on RACK_ENV the unwrapped "straight Puma" server launches. Testing this locally works but it fails on Heroku.

What's the syntax error that would cause it to fail on Heroku?

Comment: echo "Using qgsocksify to wrap Puma" `""` this is need

Comment: why not you use `if [ "$RACK_ENV" == "production" ]` next line `then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently sh doesn't use == for equivalence on Heroku but works locally on my Mac which is why it works in development. Googling revealed standard sh uses = for equivalence. In this case however I just changed #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash as Heroku supports bash as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$RACK_ENV" == "production" ]; then
  echo Using qgsocksify to wrap Puma
  bin/qgsocksify bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
else
  echo Using straight Puma
  bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
fi
```